# Prepositions - Onto and Aboard

Tags: prepositions

1. He jumped **onto** the bed. Does this sentence mean that he jumped from the ground to the bed?
2. He jumped **aboard** the bed. Does it mean same as "he jumped from the ground to the bed"?

Do these sentences mean that?

Does "he jumped onto the bed" mean same as "he jumped aboard the bed"?

If not, then what is their meaning?

Comment: Jump aboard? Is it a flying bed? Well, I know _onto_ shows that you move to (in the form of jumping) a position (bed) on a surface. About aboard, I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: We go **aboard** a plane, train, or ship.

Comment: **Onto** definitely means that he jumped from somewhere to the bed, but it doesn't necessarily mean from the floor.  If the sentence doesn't state anything else, that would be the reasonable assumption, but it would also be correct to write a sentence like, "The cat jumped off the chair and onto the bed."

Comment: A related question with some answers that might be helpful: ['He left his cave aboard a mountain top' - is aboard used correctly?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/88390/)

Answer (score 1):

"Onto" is the counterpart of "on", when talking about moving, so "onto the bed" is quite normal.

"Aboard" is used exclusively of vehicles (usually water, but also air or land). It can be used both for location on/in the vehicle or moving into/onto the vehicle. "Aboard the bed" sounds very strange, as if you are thinking of the bed as a vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

*X to Y*, when Y is not an infinitive, means X is in motion or wants to be in motion and Y is the destination of that motion.  It can also mean X is aimed or pointed at Y.

*X on Y* means that X is touching and usually above Y.  This is mostly used if Y is a flat, horizontal surface (where you couldn't use the word *top* due to it being flat).  It can also be used if Y is a mass transit vehicle (something you ride) or topic of conversation/argument.

*X onto Y* combines these meanings.  It means X is in motion or wants to be in motion, Y is the destination, and when the motion completes X will be touching and usually above Y, and Y is probably a flat, horizontal surface, mass transit vehicle, or topic of conversation/argument.

---

*Aboard* means you are on a mass transit vehicle such as a bus, train, plane, or boat.  It's related to the term *boarding a bus, train, etc.*  It usually but not always implies the vehicle isn't moving.

*Onto* is very general but you can't use *aboard* really for any other purpose other than the above types of vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have asked understanding of two words, for which you are bit confused:

1. onto - onto means **on to** as it is the common word to use.

   > Example: He jumped **onto** the bed.
2. aboard - aboard means either **on** or **in to**. Both of which are synonyms of word "aboard"

   > Example: In a plane crash, 33 people killed **onboard**.

Hope this helps you differentiate two words.

Comment: 'On' or 'into' are not synonyms of aboard, which Colin has explained is used with certain vehicles. In example 2, there is a difference between 'onboard' and 'on board'. http://grammarist.com/usage/onboard-on-board/  '[Plane crashes in Russia, all 62 people on board killed](https://ca.news.yahoo.com/russian-passenger-jet-crashes-55-people-board-cnn-022635484--finance.html)' is the more usual way to write it. I wouldn't say the people aboard the plane were killed 'on board' unless there was a murderer or bomb aboard the plane that killed them before the plane crashed, but others might disagree.