# 'He left his cave aboard a mountain top' - is aboard used correctly?

Tags: word-usage

Someone entered a contest I am sponsoring and a line reads:

> He left his cave *aboard* a mountain top

"Aboard" is the word in question here - Aboard is a required word as the contest has 10 given words that must be placed in a story or poem. The person makes great use of 9 out of 10 words. I do not believe 'aboard' is used correctly in this circumstance. I do not believe a cave can be aboard a mountain. Yes or No? The story written is really well minus this blip. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose it could be imagined in a science fiction story where the mountain has separated from the ground and has become a flying object used for the transportation of people.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Also, does  'leave' (*"left"*) mean 'exit' or 'leave behind'? It it means 'exit' then 'aboard' is probably not used in the way most people use it; however, a teacher should not too much to discourage students from extending word meanings.

Answer (score 4):

You are right.

According to [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aboard?q=Aboard) aboard is used about a person or thing that is in or on a **vehicle**. Some people also use the term about being on horseback.

[Merriam webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aboard) offers two additional meanings: alongside and membership of a team.

The **alongside** meaning is a [nautical](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aboard) term meaning [travelling](http://www.yourdictionary.com/aboard#eEPkf5VdAKV6zO04.99) on a parallel course, or in the expression [close aboard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms), which means side by side.

None of these meanings are appropriate for caves and mountains.

Comment: Not necessarily, "*Destiny climbed aboard and straddled her.*". Also it could mean _'part of a thing or a team'_ - "Welcome aboard the marketing team".

Comment: It's very clear now. +1

Comment: I think it would be really helpful to explain that the "alongside" definition is nautical - [the sailboat passed our ship close aboard](http://www.yourdictionary.com/aboard#eEPkf5VdAKV6zO04.99)

Answer (score 2):

As an adverb, "aboard" may also  have the meanings "to the side" and "side by side", and as a preposition - "on", "in", "into"

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aboard?s=t) : aboard (adverb) 2. alongside; to the side.

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/aboard) : aboard (adv)
1. side by side

[Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aboard) : aboard (adv.)
2. alongside; to the side.

So I think that the person you mentioned had thought twice before he decided to put the word into the text. Although "on a mountain top" would've been by all means a better choice.

Comment: Please include the actual dictionary entries here rather than only including the links to the dictionary... the entries can change or the site can change their links, so the links may become unuseful.

Comment: Actually, every one of the three links leads to a page with the word "aboard", not to a home page, is that is what you mean.

Comment: No. We have a rule on SE that answers should include the main content of the answer **in the content** of the answer. It's explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Link-reliant answers are considered substandard and should be improved by including the content of the link in the actual answer.

Comment: I edited one of the links as an example. I don't think this is all that helpful, because it doesn't explain how any of those definitions make 'aboard' correct in the context. All you're saying is that the author tried.

Comment: Also, as ColleenV noted in her comment on another answer, the "side by side" definition of _**aboard**_ is a nautical term.  I have _never_ heard it used in any circumstance other than boats floating in water next to each other.

Comment: @Adam You've never heard an airline flight attendant say "welcome aboard"? Really?

Comment: @Catija I think Adam meant "in the sense of alongside", not that he had never heard the word aboard used. These character limited comments make real communication a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, this is a difficult thing to answer.  Taken on its own without the rest of the writing, it feels wrong.  If the writer is trying to create a metaphor for the mountain being like a vehicle of some sort, then it might be perfectly appropriate.

I think context matters here a great deal, especially if it is poetry or fiction.